# Auto populate form options

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm having some difficulties making my next drop down selections work on this form, when you select a format you then get asked to choose the product type in the next box , I then need another option where once you select the product type e.g. PS3 headsets, you then get a list of products to choose from. Can't figure out how to get this next box working, here is my progress so far.

**http://jsfiddle.net/maximus83/r7MN9/639/**

```
    <select id="cat">
    <option val="PS3">PS3</option>
    <option val="Xbox360">Xbox360</option>
    <option val="WiiU">WiiU</option>
    <option val="Multiformat">Multiformat</option>
</select>

<select id="item">

</select>

<select id="product">

</select>
```

Here is my script

```
 PS3=new Array('Headsets(PS3)','Controllers(PS3)','Chargers(PS3)','Cables(PS3)');
Xbox360=new Array('Headsets(360)','Chargers(360)');
WiiU=new Array('Controllers(WiiU)','Headsets(WiiU)');
Multiformat=new Array('Headsets(Multi)','Chairs(Multi)','Cables(Multi)');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');

       eval(cat).forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append('<option val="#item">'+t+'</option>');


        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you tied to this data format?  This would be much simpler/cleaner if you used different array dimensions.

Comment: No I'm not tied, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you normalise the data into a single array, you can then filter the data to populate the selects based on user input. This also means that the multi-format items show as relevant items for each device.

http://jsfiddle.net/fvL0qgrx/2/

HTML

```
<select id="device"></select>
<select id="item"></select>
<select id="product"></select>
```

Javascript

```
var products = [
    { label: 'ps3 headset 1', category: 'headsets', devices: ['ps3'] },
    { label: 'ps3 headset 2', category: 'headsets', devices: ['ps3'] },
    { label: 'xbox headset 1', category: 'headsets', devices: ['xbox'] },
    { label: 'xbox headset 2', category: 'headsets', devices: ['xbox'] },
    { label: 'wii headset 1', category: 'headsets', devices: ['wii'] },
    { label: 'wii headset 2', category: 'headsets', devices: ['wii'] },
    { label: 'multi headset no wii', category: 'headsets', devices: ['ps3', 'xbox'] },
    { label: 'multi headset 1', category: 'headsets', devices: ['ps3', 'xbox', 'wii'] },

    { label: 'ps3 charger 1', category: 'chargers', devices: ['ps3'] },
    { label: 'ps3 charger 2', category: 'chargers', devices: ['ps3'] },
    { label: 'ps3 charger 3', category: 'chargers', devices: ['ps3'] },
    { label: 'xbox charger 1', category: 'chargers', devices: ['xbox'] },
    { label: 'wii charger 1', category: 'chargers', devices: ['wii'] },
    { label: 'wii charger 2', category: 'chargers', devices: ['wii'] },
    { label: 'multi charger no ps3', category: 'chargers', devices: ['wii', 'xbox'] }
];


var devices = [];
_.forEach(products, function(product){
    _.forEach(product.devices, function(device){
        if(devices.indexOf(device) === -1){
            devices.push(device);
        };
    });
});

var getCategoriesForDevice = function(device){
    var categories = _.chain(products)
        .filter(function(product){
            return product.devices.indexOf(device) !== -1;
        })
        .map(function(product){
            return product.category
        })
        .uniq()
        .value();
    return categories;
};


var getProductsForDeviceCategory = function(device, category){
    return _.filter(products, function(product){
        return product.category === category && product.devices.indexOf(device) !== -1;
    });
};



$(function() {

    var $device = $('#device');
    var $item = $('#item');
    var $product = $('#product');

    $device.html('<option value=></option>');
    _.forEach(devices, function(device){
        $device.append('<option>' + device + '</option>');
    });

    $device.on('change', function(evt){
        var $el = $(this);
        var value = $el.val();
        var data = [];
        if(value){
            data = getCategoriesForDevice(value);
        }
        $item.html('<option value=></option>');
        _.forEach(data, function(option){
            $item.append('<option>' + option + '</option>');
        }); 
    });

    $item.on('change', function(evt){
        var $el = $(this);
        var value = $el.val();
        var data = [];
        if(value){
            data = getProductsForDeviceCategory($device.val(), value);
        }
        $product.html('<option val=></option>');
        _.forEach(data, function(option){
            $product.append('<option>' + option.label + '</option>');
        }); 
    });

});
```

PS. Don't use eval - it's on par with pledging your first born child to the devil.